# Simplified vector equation and geometric representation

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

[image]

> Find a simple vector equation for $B$ and describe the set geometrically.

So we let corresponding constants be $c_1, c_2, c_3 \in \mathbb{R}$ for the vectors.

$$\overrightarrow{x} = c_1\overrightarrow{v_1}  + c_2\overrightarrow{v_2}  + c_3\overrightarrow{v_3} $$

So I get

$$\overrightarrow{x} = \begin{bmatrix} c_1 + c_2 + 3c_3 
\\ c_3
\\ c_1 + 2c_2
\\ c_1 + c_2
\end{bmatrix}$$

But what does this represent geometrically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the vectors are linear independent, their span is a plane $(3-$flat) in $R^4$ through the zero vector.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

You need to solve for $s,t,u, v$ in and get an equation involving these.
\begin{align*} 
c_1 + c_2 + 3c_3 & = s\\ 
c_3 & = t\\ 
c_1 + 2c_2 & = u\\ 
c_1 + c_2 & = v
\end{align*}
Which amounts to
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 3 & | s\\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & | t\\ 
1 & 2 & 0 & | u\\ 
1 & 1 & 0 & | v\\ 
\end{bmatrix}
\longrightarrow
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 3 & | &s\\ 
0 & 1 & -3 & | &u-s\\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & | &t\\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & | &v-s+3t
\end{bmatrix}
$$
So for consistency you need...